# Android - sent ImageView resource through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, resources

I want sent ImageView resource through intent not to sent the image. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you can't pass `View`s through `Intent`s.

Comment: why you need it? You are trying to accomplish your task in a weird way. Describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: is it possible to change imageview visibility from service?

Comment: I want to set image to imageview from service

Comment: @Lamiya : is your image resource present in drawables or at a local device directory ?

Comment: look, In my all activities there is an Imageview which is invisible. I need to show for example 10 images each for 10 sec in this imageview. I don't want if someone goes from one activity to another, images be started from first.
@VladMatvienko

Comment: By *"ImageView resource"* do you mean a resource ID like `R.drawable.my_image`?

Comment: you can tell Activity to change ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Send image uri in intent and then by use setImageURI() method to set it to image view